# SonarQube 5.1 Adding Custom Rule for java

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I have implemented Sonar Java Plug-in(Maven) following the example here : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules. Copied the  generated sonar-plugin in /extensions/plugins directory. Restarted the SonarQube server and ran the analysis using the mvn sonar:sonar.

I can see the new Rules being added in Rules tab but no issues are being logged and also the status of Rule is active. Looks like the Rules are not considered at the time of analysis. Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable your new rules on a quality profile.

Comment: Activated the new rule for 'Sonar Way' profile by logging as Admin and Ran the analysis one again. I still don't see any issues being logged. Is there anything else need to be done after activating the rule ?

Comment: It started working after setting up the Database, instead of using the H2 Embedded Database.